# Java - Synchronized Object/Block

Tags: java, synchronization

I am looking for clarification about synchronized blocks. Consider this class -

```
public class A{
Map map;

 public getValue(String key){
  return map.get(key);
 }

 public remove(String key){
  synchronized(map){
   map.remove(key);
  }
 }
}
```

A is a singleton. getValue is heavily accessed throughout the app by multiple threads. I am adding a new method, remove, that removes a key from the map. If remove is implemented as above,

1. When a thread is in the synchronized block of the remove method, I assume it will acquire a lock on the map object. Does that mean other threads trying to access the map via the getValue method will be blocked? (I'd like them to.)
2. When no thread is in the synchronized block of remove method, will threads accessing the getValue method function as usual i.e. not block each other? (I'd like that too).

I want the getValue threads to block only if there is a thread performing the remove operation.

Comment: only blocks which are synchronized will block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one rule of synchronized is that only one thread can be in a `synchronized(foo)` block at a time, for the same foo. That's the *only* rule of `synchronized`.

Well, there's some complicated stuff about memory barriers and the like, and a *single* thread can be in several nested `synchronized(foo)` blocks for the same `foo` at the same time:

```
void thing() {
  synchronized(foo) {
    stuff(); // this works fine!
  }
}
void stuff() {
  synchronized(foo) {
    doMoreStuff();
  }
}
```

... but the rule stated above is basically the key to understanding `synchronized`.

Answer (score 4):

> When a thread is in the synchronized block of the remove method, I assume it will acquire a lock on the map object. Does that mean other threads trying to access the map via the getValue method will be blocked?

No. Which means you've got a problem, unless you happen to be using a thread-safe map implementation.

> When no thread is in the synchronized block of remove method, will threads accessing the getValue method function as usual i.e. not block each other? (I'd like that too).

They won't block each other, no. Again, you'll need to make sure that's okay with whichever `Map` implementation you're using, although it's much more *likely* to be okay than reading at the same time as writing.

You should consider using a [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) implementation (e.g. [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)), at which point you don't need any synchronization at all.

If you can't use that, I'd recommend synchronizing in *both* `getValue` and `remove` - and *measuring* the performance. Acquiring an uncontended lock is reasonably cheap - do you really *need* to go lock-free? (Using `ConcurrentHashMap` is a fairly simple way of avoiding the issue, of course, but you should always consider whether extra complexity is *needed* to achieve the performance you require before you start micro-optimizing.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So, when you say synchronized(object), does it mean that two threads if they reach that block of code must wait on each other to work with the synchronized object? That is only threads in that method will block on each other for access to the object? Thanks!

Comment: @septerr: No, not just threads in that method - any thread trying to synchronize on that object's monitor. Basically, imagine each object comes with a padlock attached. Nothing *automatically* locks the padlock, but only one thread can lock it at a time, wherever it's asked to lock it.

Comment: The one rule of `synchronized` is that only one thread can be in a `synchronized(foo)` block at a time, for the same `foo`.  That's the _only_ rule of `synchronized`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Well, there's also the memory barrier side of things... and that the `foo` expression is only evaluated once, and the same monitor is released as was acquired, even if the value of `foo` changes...

Comment: Eh, fair.  Rephrase: 80% of StackOverflow questions about `synchronized` can be answered by some special case of that one rule.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman post your comment as an answer, so I can select it. Although almost all other answers are great, yours helped me most in getting the picture of what synchronize(object) means straight. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly your need, you could take a look at the [ConcurrentMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) and of course [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)  which I believe was introduced with Java 5.0 and supports a level of concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how the Map instance is instantiated, but assuming it is not a thread-safe collection instance, this code is *not* thread-safe.

Comment: It is a regular HashMap. Thanks for the answer. I am trying to make it thread safe without impacting performance. The remove method will be called rarely while the getValue will be called a lot. I will read up on ConcurrentMap.

Answer (score 0):

**1. getValue() is not synchronized, when a thread acquires the lock of an object, it has the control over all the synchronized blocks... not the Non-synchronized one..**
 So **other threads can access the getValue() when as thread is in sychronized(map) block**

**2. Use HashTable, which is a sychronized MAP**

Answer (score 0):

You have a chicken and egg problem with

> I want the getValue threads to block only if there is a thread performing the remove operation.

Without some sort of inter-thread interaction, you cannot figure out whether there is some other thread performing a `remove`.

The correct way to implement `getValue(...)` is to synchronize on the map.

I recommend dropping your own locking, and using a `ConcurrentHashMap` and utilizing a lot of work into concurrent performance.